# Access local webserver on port 8080 in home network using IP-Address

Tags: port, tcp, windows-firewall

this is quite new to me so I hope it is clear what I try to ask.

On my windows 10 pro I have installed a small application which runs as a webserver on port 8080. I can access it using localhost:8080 or using the computers IP-address 192.168.xxx.xxx:8080.  This all works fine. However, I thought I should be able to access this site from another device in my home network as well. Typing the 192.168.xxx.xxx:8080 in the browser of this device (ipad). But this doesn't work. "This site cannot be reached".

Searching the internet, let me to the firewall. I see a few rules are added for this application. Both for the UDP and TCP protocol settings are added and for each protocol private and public rules. First I switched off the firewall then I was able to request the site from another device. So it is a firewall setting. Now I found out I had to set the public inbound rule to Allow connection. But as far as I know I'm on a local network, So why can't I access my computer using the 192.168.xxx.xxx:8080 from another device on the same network only allowing private access set to allow to connect? I'm afraid that allowing public access connection my computer is open for everybody.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thx

Comment: It has been quite a while. Do you still need help with this? If so, what problem do you have? If not, please accept my answer so others know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how your network connection is setup.

When you make a connection to a wifi point, it is usually set to Public, whereas a LAN connection is usually set as a Home connection or Work connection.

Each of these settings bring security settings with it. Public is the most secure as it denies most firewall traffic by default, whereas Home and Work allow more by default.

The home and work networks are seen by the firewall as Private, whereas the public is seen as public.

In order to find out what type of connection yours is set to, right-click your network icon, then press `open network and sharing center`.

Below *View your active networks* at the top left, it will state your network connection and below that the type.

In the past, it was possible to change the type of connection, but in Windows 10 it seems most of the time the network is set as public automatically.

That being said, even if your connection is set as public, allowing the port in the firewall as public is still secure because you have a router too. The router need to open ports in order for outside traffic to be able to get to your webserver, so allowing your firewall to access port 8080 for the public group is perfectly fine.

Comment: I have been struggling with this past few days. Let me know if you would like for me to post this as another question so you get more credit. I can easily access an app running on port 3000 from any device on LAN, but just not for 8080, and from 3 windoze boxes. I have disable firewall on all my devices. The connection is set as public on all. I still get the exact issues OP gets. Trying to set the port via command-line - so many different answers in this site, none work for me (npm giving different errors each time :( ).

Comment: @killjoy If you set your connection as public, the firewall is more strict and different firewall rules may fire. Given that you are not the OP, it may be better for you to post a new question. Feel free to link to this question and tell us what exactly doesn't work. (given you still need help after reading this comment)

Comment: Woah, now that requires a whole new thought experiment :) I always thought Private n/ws were more strict, and I assumed you suggested OP's n/w be Public because of this. Guess we are victim of  MS's play on reversing word meanings as usual.

Comment: @killjoy it actually follows Apple logic. Set it to public because you are in a public space, so you don't want everyone to be able to do everything. Set it to private because only you can access it and people you trust, so you don't care that they can reach places that are off limits to guests. You usually use private so you don't want to configure every little aspect to ensure things work correctly, whereas with public you do because you must.

Comment: Counter-intuitive to my bird-brain

Comment: posted https://superuser.com/questions/1344972/access-to-local-ip-on-port-3000-works-but-8080-does-not