# Access to local IP on port 3000 works but 8080 does not

Tags: windows, networking, port

I went through the answers on 
[Access local webserver on port 8080 in home network using IP-Address](https://superuser.com/questions/1228430/access-local-webserver-on-port-8080-in-home-network-using-ip-address)
but it still did not address my issue.

Why would I be able to access a remote (non-localhost) server on LAN via port 3000 and not 8080

Firewall off on all (Win) devices, even though port 3000 didnt require that

Comment: Is the server you are trying to access actually configured to listen to port 8080?

Comment: :) yes, I can access it locally just not from another machine within my LAN, I am starting to consider it is something else other than port#: why their npm config would be so different is beyond me. Vanilla awsAmplify starter works fine remotely. awsAmplify-Vue starter doesn't.

Comment: * I meant appSync-react starter, not awsAmplify starter

Comment: You may want to edit your post and include as much information as to what your server does and how it is configured. Before you do, it's going to be a guessing game as to why its not working.

Comment: Agreed, in the meantime the amplify-vue team has ack'd its a bug so should I delete this post ?

Comment: If it's a bug, then yeah, the post can be deleted.